# Python syntax error in class practice problem

Tags: python, class, methods, instance

I'm attempting some practice problems to learn more about classes in Python, and upon running this code, I'm getting a syntax error on line 11 (`print(f"The restaurant's name is: {self.restaurant_name}. The restaurant serves: {self.cuisine_type}.")`). I've checked my code over and over again with no success in finding a solution to my problem, and I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out what's going wrong. I've also tried removing the `describe_restaurant` method from the class, and just keeping the `open_restaurant` method, and I still receive a syntax error, but now it's on line 15. I tried to find an answer to this problem on another question forum but I couldn't find anything that was of use to me. I'm a novice programmer, so I apologize if I made a stupid mistake in my code. Thanks!

```
class Restaurant:
    """A simple attempt to model a restaurant."""

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        """Initialize restaurant name and cuisine type attributes."""
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        """Give a brief description of the restaurant."""
        print(f"The restaurant's name is: {self.restaurant_name}. The restaurant serves: {self.cuisine_type}.")

    def open_restaurant(self):
        """Display a message that the restaurant is open."""
        print(f"{self.restaurant_name} is open!")

restaurant = Restaurant('Hard Rock Cafe', 'American Grub')

print(f"{restaurant.restaurant_name} serves {restaurant.cuisine_type}.")

restaurant.describe_restaurant()
restaurant.open_restaurant()
```

```
print(f"The restaurant's name is: {self.restaurant_name}. The restaurant serves: {self.cuisine_type}.")
                                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: are you running your python on 2.7?

Comment: what is the "f" char before the string in the printf statement?

Comment: f strings where introduced in Python 3.6, you must be running an older version.

Comment: See [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) in the documentation.

Comment: In the text you tell us that the error occurs within the "describe_restaurant" method, but at the end of your post you show that the error occurs outside of the class. Assuming the last is correct when copying and running the code, I agree with Thierry. Otherwise please correct the question.

Comment: I was indeed running Python 2.7, rookie mistake on my part. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are running on old python version:

f-string work  on  python >= 3.6 version
see the pep [python pep498 f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)
`python2.7`

```
a  = 12345
print(f"python2.7 don't support f-strint {a}")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(f"python2.7 don't support f-strint {a}")
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`python3.8`

```
a = 12345                                                                                                                                                                                          

print(f"but on python >3.6 f-strinf work {a}")                                                                                                                                                     
but on python >3.6 f-strinf work 12345
```

Comment: That did the trick, I just needed to update my settings.json file in VS Code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Check your python version 
`f` is introduced for python 3.6 and above
so it does not work in python2

Answer (score 0):

If you are still using python2 change the print statement string format from

```
print(f"{restaurant.restaurant_name} serves {restaurant.cuisine_type}.")
```

to

```
print(" {} serves {} " .format(restaurant.restaurant_name,restaurant.cuisine_type))
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. I just needed to update my settings.json file in VS Code. Thank you!